# How to connect mssql data base through JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have one data base that is enabled ssl. How to connect that data base through JDBC driver.
I have tried jdbc:sqlserver://10.29.34.222:1433;databaseName=test this jdbc url is worked for both ssl enabled database and ssl not enabled database.
What cloud be the exact jdbc url for ssl is enabled or not enabled time.?

Answer (score 1):

can you try with :

```
String connectionUrl =   
    "jdbc:sqlserver://10.29.34.222:1433;" +  
     "databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;" +  
     "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
```

For more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-with-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If database base ssl is enabled url should be different and 
if ssl is not enabled then url should be different. Those url's I am looking.